# Is there a global variable that reflects the current preferred table column's width?

Tags: tables, width, cell, column-width

I wish to insert a (varwidth) box into a table cell, and I want the size of the box to be limited in width to whatever autosize that column would otherwise have, and for any text that I insert into the box to just wrap at that width.

I was initially hoping to be able to do something like

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3\tabularnewline
stuff & 
\begin{varwidth}{\columnwidth}
This text should be wrapped to the width of the column
but instead it makes the entire column extremely wide
\end{varwidth}
 & stuff\tabularnewline
some other stuff & some other stuff & some other stuff\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

Putting my `varwidth` minipage in the cell where I want to insert the text, but \columnwidth seems to only reflect the width of a column with respect to how the pages are finally laid out, not the preferred width of an individual table column.   Worse this example further causes the table to overflow past the right margin.

I apologize in advance if my requirements are unclear, but if any one has any specific questions, I will try to address them quickly and clarify the text of this question as appropriate.

Comment: So you know the width of the widest element in one specific column, and you want another element to not exceed this width? Is this an `l`, `c` or `r` column?

Comment: You could use `\sbox1{\hbox{<Largest Column Item >}` and then at the place you want to add the item `\parbox{\wd\sbox1}{\hfil<Your item here>\hfill}`. Use `\hfil` and `\hfill` for centered item etc.

Comment: questions are always clearer if you provide a complete small document showing the problem, normally multiline things are in a `p` column in which case `\linewidth` is the answer. For `l`,`c`,`r` columns you could do do a two pass solution, or perhaps using tabularx `X` would meet the need, hard to say...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I've tried to give a more complete example of what I was hoping to do, but as this doesn't actually do what I want, I'm not sure how helpful it is at describing my intent.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not really automatic as you have to determine the widest entry manually, but might give you something close to what you described:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cC{\widthof{some other stuff}}c}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3\tabularnewline
stuff & 
This text should be wrapped to the width of the column
but instead it makes the entire column extremely wide
 & stuff\tabularnewline
some other stuff & some other stuff & some other stuff\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes... but in fact, if I knew which entry was otherwise the widest, I could just use that width for the `varwidth` entry itself.  I would ideally like a solution that is more reusable, and independent of the entry that happens to have the widest entry.